# MySQL - two tables, compare two rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables with the same content one is an older copy of the first table. So the live table could have a price change. I'm trying to build a query to find the prices changes in old records.

`Products`

`ID`

`Title`

`Price`

Old table

`Old_Products`

`ID`

`Title`

`Price`

Im using this query so far but does not do what i want.

```
SELECT products.id
FROM products
LEFT JOIN products_old ON products.id = products_old.id
WHERE products.price IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craft your where clause to determine where the price is not equal between the old and new table.

```
SELECT products.id, products.title, products.price, products_old.price
FROM products
JOIN products_old ON products.id = products_old.id
WHERE products.price <> products_old.price
```

If this simple query is performing poorly on your database I would suggest inspecting the indexes you have applied on both tables.  Also, as mentioned by ypercube, using a simple inner join will be more efficient than using an outer join.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this Kevin - Our database has over a million records and it takes ages for this query to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @okett I'm not sure how to optimize a simple join, this query is pretty basic.  Do you have indexes built on the id and price columns?

Comment: No i didn't have any added - Just attached some and query runs in under 30 seconds. Thank you :)

Comment: @ypercube What would you suggest rather than LEFT JOIN? #Update - By changing to JOIN cuts it down to under 20 seconds.

Comment: See the update by Kevin. A left join would return all rows from the new `products` table.